# Created a verification system with Discord.JS but I get no response to my command setting it up

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

So I'm creating my first Discord bot to try and gain experience coding, of course running into a lot of problems but most of them I was able to solve myself. This problem however I can't.
The goal of the code is that I can send a command and that the bot will then set-up the verification in that channel. However when I send that command the bot doesn't respond, no ERROR in cmd either.

To find out when the problem occured I added "console.log(Verification process has started", didn't get that in the logs either.

Code Verification:

```
const { DiscordAPIError } = require("discord.js");
const { execute } = require("./ping");

const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    name: 'verify',
    description: 'Let them verify',
    aliases: ['Verify', 'Verification'],
    async execute(client, message, args){
        console.log('Verification process has started.')
        if(!message.member.roles.cache.has('955164630936850483')) return;

        const channel = '954717049890955334'
        const memberRole = '955164944482058240'
        const verifyEmoji = '✅'

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("GREEN")
        .setTitle('React To Verify!')
        .setDescription('React with "✅" to get verified in the server.')

        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed]})
        messageEmbed.react(verifyEmoji)

        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction. user))
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;  

            if(reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if(reaction.emoji.name === verifyEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(memberRole);
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove('<@955185557544263721>');
                }
            }   else {
                    return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Main code:

```
> const Discord = require("discord.js") require('dotenv').config();
> 
> const generateImage = require("./generateImage") const { MessageEmbed
> } = require("discord.js")
> 
> 
> const client = new Discord.Client({
>     intents: [
>         "GUILDS",
>         "GUILD_MESSAGES",
>         "GUILD_MEMBERS",
>         "GUILD_MESSAGES",
>         "GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS"
>     ],
>     partials: [
>         "messageCreate",
>         "CHANNEL",
>         "REACTION"
>     ] });
> 
> // Prefix const prefix = '-';
> 
> const fs = require('fs');
> 
> client.commands = []
> 
> // Command file filter for (const file of
> fs.readdirSync('./commands')) {
>     const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
> 
>     client.commands.push(command); }
> 
> // Message when bot starts up client.once('ready', () => {
>     console.log('<Omnia> is online!');
>     client.channels.cache.get(`955163442472419460`).send(`I am now back online, if you see me offline contact staff in
> <#955167864422301736>.`) });
> 
> // Automatically gives "Unverified" when someone joins the server
> 
> 
> client.on("message", async message => {
>     if (message.author.bot) return false;
>     const Role1 = message.guild.roles.cache.get("RoleID");
> 
> 
> })
> 
> // Prefix filter client.on('message', message =>{
>     if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
>     const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
>     const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
> 
>     // Go through all the commands the bot has
>     for (const cmd of client.commands) {
>         // Check if the command name matches any of the aliases
>         if (cmd.aliases.includes(command)) {
>             // TODO: Check if the command has the required permissions
>             
>             // If the command is found, run it
>             cmd.execute(client, message, args)
>         }
>     } });
> 
> const welcomeChannelId = "954724625076600872"
> 
> client.on("guildMemberAdd", async (member) => {
>     const img = await generateImage(member);
>     member.guild.channels.cache.get(welcomeChannelId).send({
>         content: `<@${member.id}> *Make sure to invite your friends!*`,
>         files: [img]
>     }) }) client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);
```

Comment: Removed the pictures and added the code.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that I had `async execute(client, message, args){` while it should've been `execute: (client, message, args) =>{`